# Twitter timeline integration in Swift (SwiftHTTP)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, twitter, oauth

I am trying to create a twitter timeline in Swift. I am using SimpleAuth aswell as SwiftHTTP. I successfully authorize Twitter in another class and get the access token and the user ID.

```
class func getTwitterFeed() {
var request = HTTPTask()
request.requestSerializer = JSONRequestSerializer()
request.GET("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json", parameters: ["user_id": twitterUserID], success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
    if let twitterTimelineDictionary = response.responseObject as? NSData {
        let str = NSString(data: twitterTimelineDictionary, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("response: \(str)") //prints the HTML of the page
    }
    },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
        println("error: \(error)")
})
```

}
In the console I get:

> error: Error Domain=HTTPTask Code=400 "An error occured"
>   UserInfo=0x7fdd5da288b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred}

According to Twitter - error code 400 means the request is invalid or there is no authentication. Should I be using the access token somehow? Am I doing something completely wrong / any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem just some minutes ago with a self-implemented WCF REST service...
The only way I found to make it work is the following:

```
request.requestSerializer = JSONRequestSerializer()
request.GET(... // your code
```

I think it's all about how the parameters' format expected by the server..
I hope to have been of help!

Comment: Ok, so I added the `request.requestSerializer = JSONRequestSerializer()` and I still get the exact same error. Do you have any idea how I should format the request properly, and do I need to use the auth/access token in the request, because currently I am not.

Comment: Uhm, I'll test my code with the Twitter API you used above and I'll make you know asap!